# how to set the value of a variable in repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

i want call a function in aspx page in the repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Rpt_M" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="noktaDetay.aspx?id=1" ><%# Container.DataItem(1)%></a>
    <%Dim yorumid As Integer = Eval("DnAd")
      Dim yorumadet = yorumsay(yorumid)
      Dim yorumyaz As String = yorumadet + " adet yorum var"
      If yorumadet = 0 Then yorumyaz = "bla bla bla"%>
    <a href="yorumlar.aspx?id=1"><%=yorumyaz%></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

When I run the code I get this error:

Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

How can I set the value for yorumid instead of using eval("DnAd")?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `IIf` operator

```
<a href="yorumlar.aspx?id=1"><%# IIf(yorumsay(Eval("DnAd")) = 0, "bla bla bla", yorumsay(Eval("DnAd")) + " adet yorum var")%></a>
```

It is called ternary operator in C#

```
<a href="yorumlar.aspx?id=1"><%# yorumsay(Eval("DnAd")) = 0 ? "bla bla bla" : yorumsay(Eval("DnAd")) + " adet yorum var")%></a>
```

I believe the `yorumsay()` method is available to your page already

Comment: yes but the problem i can not use yorumsay(yorumid) because yorumid has no value. how can I assign the rowid value to yorumid?
yorumsay(id as integer) is a simple function that counts the rows in a table and returns the value.

Comment: Check my update: Replace `yorumid` with `Eval("DnAd")`

Comment: it is sorted. Thank you codingbiz :)